# Applying over a vector of functions

Tags: r

Given a vector (actually a list) of functions:

```
 fs = c(sin, cos, tan)
```

and a vector of values:

```
 xs = c(.1, .3, .5)
```

Is there a better/neater/faster/stronger way of computing `fs[[i]](xs[i])` for each vector element:

```
 vapply(1:3, FUN.VALUE = 1 ,function(i){fs[[i]](xs[i])})
  [1] 0.09983342 0.95533649 0.54630249
```

Or am I missing a `fapply` function somewhere? The functions will always be functions of a single scalar value and returning a single scalar value.

Comment: That there is no shortcut to `function(fun, ...) fun(...)` has always bothered me (`do.call` is close but not it.) R's base package needs one IMHO.

Comment: The lack of `map`, `zip`, and `combine` functions (aka Haskell) has always irked me.

Comment: `Funcall <- function(f, ...) f(...)`  ... from `?Map`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nice and simple:

```
mapply(function(fun, x) fun(x), fs, xs)
```

But I agree with @flodel. I was also looking for a base function for `function(fun, ...) fun(...)` and was surprised that there doesn't seem to be one. On the other hand I've never needed it, so far.

Answer (score 8):

Here's an alternative whose main advantage over the suggestions so far is that it doesn't require that an anonymous function be defined.

```
mapply(do.call, fs, lapply(xs, list))
# [1] 0.09983342 0.95533649 0.54630249
```

Comment: +1 I thought about using `do.call`, but it was too obfuscating for me. I wouldn't know what this does without investigating.

Comment: Yeah, the `lapply()`'s unfortunate. It's needed because `do.call()` requires that its second argument be a list. My own preferred solution would be to write `Funcall <- function(x,...) x(...); mapply(Funcall, fs, xs)`. Seems like the clearest way to write this, and `Funcall()` has the added advantage of accepting more than one argument if it needs to (as in `mapply(Funcall, fs, xs1, xs2, ...)`).

Comment: Since `Vectorize` creates an `mapply`-based function, you could easily make this: `fapply <- Vectorize(do.call); fapply(fs, lapply(xs, list))` for slightly less typing if you want to call `fapply` multiple times.