# apply a list of functions to a single argument in R

Tags: r

Hi I am trying to apply a list of functions to a single argument in R. For example,

```
flist <- list(F,G,H) #F,G,H are function objects
```

and say I want as a result a list or vector 
`(F(x),G(x),H(x))` where x is a scalar number. 
Do you know how i can achieve that?

Comment: `myscalar <- 1 ; lapply(flist, function(x) x(myscalar))` maybe?

Comment: `Map(function(f,x){ f(x) },flist,3)` is another option (the `3` is just an arbitrary scalar I picked).

Comment: Also take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765053/apply-a-list-of-n-functions-to-each-row-of-a-dataframe)

Comment: ah thanks! I just figured out that this works as well:      outer(flist, 0.8, Vectorize( function(a,b) a(b) ))

Comment: @NickD1, `Vectorize` is just a wrapper for `mapply`, so I wouldn't use it combined with `outer`. You can just use nrussells solution, or mine (which will probably the fastest one)

Comment: btw, `Map` is also a wrapper for `mapply`, so the cleanest version of your solution would be something like `mapply(function(f, x) f(x) ,flist, 0.8)`

Comment: I thought the lapply version was cleanest, myself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23496776/applying-over-a-vector-of-functions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most efficient way (it seems) to achieve this would be using a single `lapply` (instead of 3 different functions), such as

```
flist <- list(mean, unique, max) # Example functions list
MyScalar <- 1 # Some scalar
lapply(flist, function(f) f(MyScalar))
# [[1]]
# [1] 1
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 1
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 1
```

Though, if all the functions give the same size/class result, you could improve it even more using `vapply`

```
vapply(flist, function(x) x(MyScalar), FUN.VALUE = double(1))
## [1] 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
f <- function(x) x^1
g <- function(x) x^2
h <- function(x) x^3
l <- list(f, g, h)

sapply(l, do.call, list(2))
## [1] 2 4 8
```

`do.call` allows for function delegation with variable-length argument lists.
For example, `c(1, 2, 3)` can be called like so: `do.call(c, list(1, 2, 3))`.
`(s|l)apply` just iterates through a list and applies the specified function to each item. So the first iteration through `l` will be: `do.call(l[[1]], list(2))`, which is equivalent to `l[[1]](2)`, which is equivalent to `f(2)`.

Comment: You should explain what the code does and what are the roles of the functions.

Comment: Well, the first 4 lines are simply setting up the example.

Comment: Let's imagine I came here from a search engine, I won't learn much by reading a block of code without any explanation.

Comment: Understood, but `R` has a (very) rich set of man pages for every function, conveniently named for nearly every function. For example, `?sapply` and `?do.call`. Any explanation I can give will do those man pages an injustice :-)

Comment: Thanks, that's a recommended practice here: *Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better*, see the documentation: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Why would you use three functions such `sapply`, `do.call` and `list` instead of just a single `lapply`?

Comment: (1) To introduce the OP to the concept of expression evaluation, which is a powerful tool. (2) The two solutions are roughly equivalent in speed, if taking the time to pre-store the argument list (i.e. removing the `list` call) and `sapply`'s simplification step. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mmuurr/71365206f19d0d3fe6c1) for a rough speed comparison. Efficiency wasn't a listed concern in the OP, and when that's the case, I tend to opt for solutions with increased flexibility. Great thing about `R` is that there's no shortage of solutions! (So I up-voted your answer, too :-) Cheers!

Comment: @DavidArenburg I find the do.call version more elegant, because there's no need to create anonymous functions. Same difference as `lapply(l, function(x) x[['id']])` vs `lapply(l, "[[", 'id')`. do.call is the natural function to apply here.

Comment: @baptiste, why the lack of `function(x)` justifies so many additional functions? In the example you gave, there were no additional functions involved so I can agree with you on that, but this situation is completely different. In order to avoid `function(x)` you are adding additional 3 functions. That doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I count only 1 _additional_ "function", and list() is a pretty lightweight player. Anyway, this is just a matter of personal preference.